# ARCore with OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, arcore

I am truing to create an app that uses ArCore Camera and face detection.
Does anyone have any example of ARCore running OpenCV Object and Face detection?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this flexibility is still not available on ARCore , but you can actually work with the embedded **"Image Recognition"** feature known as "**Augmented Image**" in ARCore. It still lacks some necessities like the focus of the Camera and all but it works fine.

Comment: I want to detect an object using opencv for example a hand gesture and the place an object according to the hand gesture using AR Core. Is there a way to use the same camera and use both the sdks, I mean opencv and arcore sceneform sdk?